# Can a IP addresses for sub domains be same as main domain?

Tags: google-analytics, dns, subdomain, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I have a domain wwww.maindomian.com and 10 subdomains for example abc.maindomain.com and so on.

My question:

Is it okay to have a same IP for sub domains as main domain from SEO point of view?

Will googleanalytics code be same for both main and sub domains?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes SEO point of view, it is ok to have same IP for sub domains as main domain because in case if your one domain or sub domain penalized that doesn't mean all domains on that IP will be penalized. Read '[page level penalty](https://moz.com/blog/pagelevel-algorithmic-penalties-on-the-rise-from-google)'.

Yes, google analytics code remain the same for both main and sub domains. You can track sub domains results by setting filter. Read more from here http://www.ericmobley.net/guide-to-tracking-multiple-subdomains-in-google-analytics/